# Как красиво сказать по-русски "host operating system"?

Tags: заимствования, грамотная-речь, терминология, компьютеры

Означает "операционная система физического компьютера, на котором запущена виртуальная машина".

Виртальная машина сама выполняется на host-овой операционной системе, внутри неё работает гостевая операционная система.

- virtual machine - виртуальная машина;
- guest operating system - гостевая операционная система;
- host operating system - ____ая операционная система.

Некрасивые/неточные варианты:

- физическая;
- хостовая, host-овая, host'овая, host-система, хост-система;
- невиртуальная, внешняя;
- "операционная система, в которой (на которой?) выполняется сама виртуальная машина";
- главная, управляющая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Довольно трудно будет найти альтернативу сложившемуся термину.
Если попробовать, то как то-так. "Литературно" - ведущая или принимающая, правда крепко сомневаюсь, что это будет понятно как термин. Жаргонно - домашняя или хозяйская (что-то подобное слыхивано от "крутых" системщиков). Можно еще "мастер-система", но это двусмысленно, master-host лучше не трогать.

А чем все-таки плохо обычное **ОС хоста** или что-то подобное? Заказчик требует точности или обязательного перевода? 
Просто, если уж придираться по-настоящему, то ни "гостевая", ни какая еще операционка не прокатит из-за двусмысленности, хотя и используется сплошь и рядом. Только "ОС гостевой машины" и подобное. Поэтому "ОС хоста" представляется не только де-факто общепринятым, но и вполне разумным.

Да, забыл было. Программа (в т.ч. и гостевая ОС) выполняется **НА** машине, **В** среде ОС, и **ПОД** управлением ОС. Так что тут могут быть варианты.

Comment: `Поэтому "ОС хоста" представляется не только де-факто общепринятым, но и вполне разумным.` -> Слово "хост" не получится перевести чтобы и как термин было всем [техническим пользователям] понятно, и "руглишем" не попахивало?

Comment: Нет, сравните со спортивними терминами. 
guestы - гости, hosts - хозяева.
Полная аналогия. Host OS = "хозяйская OS". Попахивает-с, как изволили выразится, за версту. Так что - либо точность, либо благовония. Всё вместе вряд ли получится.